# PHP cURL with partial transfer

Tags: php, curl

I need to read from a URL that will never complete.

Basically, there is a web service that will *tail* a log file.  That is, it returns the last 10 lines or so of the file, and as new lines are written, it sends them immediately.  This HTTP request continues on forever.  If you were to hit it with your browser, you would see these first 10 lines and your browser's progress indicator would continue to show progress, even as nothing is displayed (until more lines are added to the log file).

I have a PHP script that needs to do something with these log lines.  What I would like to do is hit this URL with cURL, download what was available, and if the logfile is silent (that is, no more lines added) for 10 seconds or so, end the request.  I can't simply do a timeout here, because if there is a busy log file, it may download fairly continuously for some period of time.  For most logs though, writes to them are only periodic.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?  I don't see any cURL options that will be helpful, and may result to opening up a socket directly.

---

### Solution

Thanks to @Christian Sciberras, I was able to get this working.  Here is some basic example code for anyone else that needs something similar:

```
<?php
$ch=curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.whatever.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'read_body');
curl_exec($ch);

if ($error=curl_error($ch)) {
    echo "Error: ", $error;
}

function read_body($ch, $string) {
    //Any new line that comes in appears on $string.  Handle it here.
    $length=strlen($string);
    echo $length, " bytes  |  ", $string;
    return $length; //Return the number of bytes that were handled.  Anything other than the length that was sent, and cURL will error out.
}
?>
```

Also, there is more information here:  http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/callbacks.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either check the length and abort after the expected length has been achieved, or you could use a timeout, or better still, both of them.

Since you didn't bother with some code :P, I'll advise what you need to accomplish what you want. The rest is up to you.

> > CURLOPT_TIMEOUT -- The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
> >
> > CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION -- The name of a callback function where the callback function takes two parameters. The first is the cURL resource, and the second is a string with the data to be written. The data must be written by using this callback function. Must return the exact number of bytes written or this will fail.

Basically, write a function for CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION and make it  so that if buffer length is larger than your expected value, it returns 0. Returning 0 effectively makes CURL fail, hence closing the connection and continuing with your script.

Comment: Welcome! By the way, don't forget to `curl_close($ch);` after `curl_exec`.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT and CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME to have it bail out only if nothing has showed up for a specific time.

Or you can use the multi interface functions to decide completely on your own when to stop or not.